# How can I combine these 2 queries into one single query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
$other_query = $this -> db -> query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM shops WHERE cid=$cid AND zbid!=0 AND zbid!=$zbid)",__LINE__,__FILE__);
$this -> db -> output_vars["other_shops"] = $this -> db -> get_result($other_query); // 1 = there are other shops, 0 = no other shops
if($group["shop_create"] == 0){
    $my_shop = 3;
} else {            
    $my_shop_query = $this -> db -> query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM shops WHERE cid=$cid AND zbid=$zbid LIMIT 1)",__LINE__,__FILE__);
    $my_shop = $this -> db -> get_result($my_shop_query) == 1 ? 1 : 2;
}
```

I'd like to combine the two queries into one. The only difference between the two queries is that one checks for a row where `zbid!=0 AND zbid!=$zbid` whereas the other checks for a row where `zbid=$zbid`. The other problem here is the `if` statement. Also, in the case that `$group["shop_create"] == 0` (i.e in this initial code, only one query would be run), I wouldn't want the combined query to do any extra work.

For those who are curious, `$this -> db -> get_result($query_resource)` basically returns the equivalent of `mysql_result($query_resource,0)`. I added this functionality when I switched from `mysql` to `mysqli`.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I think you should read up on how `JOIN` works. [Check out this diagram](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg). It helped me a bunch.

Comment: I'm not sure how `JOIN` is relevant here as both queries access the same table.

Comment: You can join on the same table. Just use different aliases. `select a.* from my_table as a inner join my_table as b on b.parent=a.id`

Comment: What is the difference in performance in this case between joining the two identical tables and using `$mysqli -> multi_query` ?

Comment: join is always faster. I can't give exact metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:
"SELECT zbid FROM shops WHERE cid=$cid"?

Then you'll need the equivalent of mysql_fetch_* to loop the results.
Personally I'd store them in an array & do the tests afterwards.

Something like this:

```
$res = $this -> db -> query("SELECT zbid FROM shops WHERE cid=$cid",__LINE__,__FILE__);
$arr = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($res) ) {
  $arr[] = $row[0];
}
$arr = array_diff($arr, array(0));

$this -> db -> output_vars["other_shops"] = count(array_diff($arr, array($zbid)) > 0 ? 1 : 0;

if($group["shop_create"] == 0){
    $my_shop = 3;
} else {            
    $my_shop = in_array($zbid, $arr) ? 1 : 2;
}
```

Comment: That means looping through a potentially large array of information, and also querying (and returning) every row of the table.

Comment: I assume there are indexes. And I don't assume there are like 10.000 shops on 1 database. So all in all you need to decide if 2 queries cause more load than 1 query and looping them in memory...